# simple Flask shows blank page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a simple `application.py` script to run flask along with an html pages `index.html` and `layout.html` in a templates directory. When I run flask with `flask run`, nothing happens. I go to the link but the page is completely blank, despite it supposed to be showing "hello".

I have flask and jinja2 installed. Is there anything else that is needed? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

application.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

layout.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <p>hello</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html` Your block should be :

`{% block body %} {% endblock %}`

Not
`{% block main %} {% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you : I used vscod and occurred this problem when the save change automatically was off so when i turned that on the problem solved.